# Possible to keep materials after remesh?

Tags: modeling, remesh

I'd like to:
Join multiple meshes/objects with Ctrl+J, they all have different materials.
Is it possible to preserve material data where it's remeshed?

Comment: are we talking about materials with uv and image textures? Or simple colors?

Comment: Materials, not baked textures.

Comment: Join - keeps materials ... Remesh - generates completely new topology and materials are not preserved since they are originally assigned to a specific vertices.